# Unable to open sleep image due to permission issues

Tags: macos, mac, permission, high-sierra

I upgraded my Mac to High Sierra and I wanted to open the sleep image which is situated in `/private/var/vm` But when I opened it it showed 'you have no acces to open this file please contact your administrator or network administrator' message like that.I am not sure whether this is a problem with me or has Apple restricted access to sleep image on high sierra

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find these keys on your keyboard command+I this will open the get info window

After the windows opens scroll down and click on the sharing & permission

Now if you don't see your username in the filed which appears after clicking on sharing & permissions then add your username (Admin) by clicking on the plus sign

Now if this doesn't works then again click on the plus sign and add Administrator (First check is Administrator is visible in the filed or not after clicking sharing and permission)

After pressing command+i you will get to see a window like this after which you will have to click on the lock icon!

[image]

Then enter your password

[image]

Now a second overlaying window will appear on your mac screen

Now, You will have to select either your username or administrators and add it to the sharing and permissions field

After that there wouldn't be any permission issues!

[image]

Comment: doesn't work. I don't have necessary permissions to add my name or my group. Sorry. Furthermore this sleepimage is corrupted and the answer seems to delete this file but impossible. Very irritating because my mac book pro restart in the middle of the night every night even though it's closed

Comment: Try deleting it by entering `sudo rm -r /private/var/vm` this will erase it no matter what